# I am looking for suggestions on how to implement banner ads utilizing google type ads (or someone else)

Tags: advertising

In order to help pay for our drupal 6 website we need to be able to derive some revenue from banner ads.  I am looking for suggestions on how to implement banner ads utilizing google type ads (or someone else) so that the ads display within a predefined rectangle and if the users clicks on an ad (which takes them to a new tab/page) it gives our company some revenue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common ad network is [Adsense](https://www.google.com/adsense/). You will have to sign up for an account and then you can install the [Adsense module](http://drupal.org/project/adsense) which will manage your ads for you.

Beware however, this isn't a get rich quick type situation. Making money of Adsense requires a high volume of traffic.

Comment: Our adsense account was disapproved because the majority of the pages are behind a login even though the majority of the content within these pages that allow you to login can be accessed without a login.  Any suggestions for other ad networks that I could establish an account?